# Flannery compensation in Leaflet JS

Tags: leaflet, thematic-map

I'm creating a bubble map using Leaflet JS. Everything is working smoothly (LeafletJS is awesome!) but now I'd like to try flannery compensation on the bubbles.

I can't find the math anywhere though. Best explainations I've been able to find say you have to multiply radius by either 1.4 or 1.8, which just seems a bit useless.

What is the math used for Flannery compensation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Flannery Appearance Compensation case:
Pj = 1.0083 * (Valj/ValMin)^0.5716 * Pmin

Where:
Pj = point size of the j'th feature
Valj = value of the j'th feature
ValMin = minimum value
Pmin = minimum point size
^0.5 is to the power of 0.5 (square root)
^0.5716 is to the power of 0.5716
```

More to be found at http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1730&t=213906.

Comment: `Pmin` seems to act more like a maximum point size, but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote up a little JS function based on @zimmi's formula that takes in a geojson, the name of the attribute, and the value for the minimum point size. Based on that it puts circles on the map.

```
var flanneryCompensation = function(geojsonName, attributeName, pMin) {
    // Creates a Flannery Appearence Compensation
    var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(geojsonName);

    var valMin = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;;
    geojsonLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        // Get minimum value of all features
        var value = layer.feature.properties[attributeName];
        if (value < valMin) valMin = value;
    });

    geojsonLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        var value = layer.feature.properties[attributeName];

        // Flannery Appearance Compensation case:
        pValue = 1.0083 * Math.pow(value/valMin, 0.5716) * pMin

        var circleLayer = L.circle(layer._latlng, pValue);
        circleLayer.bindPopup(String(value));
        circleLayer.addTo(map);
    });
};
```

A JSFiddle with some sample data: http://jsfiddle.net/mwvdlee/jH2EY/1/

Comment: The "^" is an XOR in javascript, so results were not as expected. Changing the actual Flannery line to `pValue = 1.0083 * Math.pow(value/valMin, 0.5716) * pMin` makes it work. http://jsfiddle.net/mwvdlee/jH2EY/1/

Comment: @Martijn Cool, thanks for catching that. I updated my answer.

Comment: In your example why is pMin 10,000?